# Angular 16 effects,signals, computes

Tags: angular, rxjs, signals, reactive, effects

I'm a junior developer and I'm currently trying to familiarize myself with the new features in Angular 16. I know that the new tools (effects, signals, computes) are very powerful, but I don't fully understand how they work yet. I'm trying to make an API call without using a subscription. We can assume that the following code works (but with a subscription):

```
@Component( {
  selector: 'easy-planer-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './login.component.scss' ]
} )
export class LoginComponent {

  formGroup: FormGroup;
  k = signal<UserCredential> ({ credential: null, user: null })
  // @ts-ignore
  constructor( private fb: FormBuilder, private readonly authService: AuthService, private readonly router: Router ) {
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group( {
      email: new FormControl<string>( '', [ Validators.required, Validators.email ] ),
      password: new FormControl<string>( '', [ Validators.required, Validators.minLength( 8 ) ] )
    } );
    if(this.k().user?.isAnonymous){
      console.log(this.k)
      // this.router.navigate(['/home'])
    }
  }


  loginWithEmailAndPassword(): void {
    const email = this.formGroup?.get( 'email' )?.value;
    const password = this.formGroup?.get( 'password' )?.value;
    signal( this.authService.login( email, password ).pipe(
      tap( () => {console.log("hello"); this.navigateOnLoggedInState();} )
    ) );
  }

  loginWithGoogle(): void {
    this.authService.googleLogin().subscribe(credentials => this.k.set(credentials))
   

  }

  private navigateOnLoggedInState() {
    if ( this.authService.isLoggedIn ) {
      this.router.navigate( [ '/home' ] );
    }
  }

  logout() {
    this.authService.logout()
  }
}
```

I intentionally commented out the attempted code and provided it for reference. I understand that I somehow need to listen to the click event, but I'm not sure how to do it correctly so that I don't have to use a subscription in the loginWithGoogle method. Just to add, the goal is to navigate to the Home page once logged in

I'm trying to make an API call without using a subscription by using a click event and utilizing the new features of signals and effects.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you can't pass an Observable to the `signal` constructor. You can use the `toSignal` from the `@angular/core/rxjs-interop` package to make the conversion if you like:

```js
const signal = toSignal(this.authService.login) // etc etc
```

You would then return that signal to the caller method to be used like any other signal.

WARNING: This is all still developer preview, so definitely not to be used in production.

Comment: I think I have misunderstood the architecture a bit. I need to respond to the Observable in the service and query the variable in the component.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "respond" in the service? By returning the signal to the component, you can then use its contents.